# How share one Linq-to-sql for Multi-Project With Dll Layers?

Tags: sql, linq, project, connection-string

i have multiProject that it have one main project.
this main project have one linq-to-sql Dbml and other project have new class from this and use it.and mainproject have dll of other project.
if install this application on other computer and change connectionString on mainproject,other dll of project can change own connectionString ? and connect to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DAL inside "main" project then once you change connection string it will work, otherwise check you lib for app.config